# How can I pass values from javascript var to executeSql?

Tags: javascript

How can I pass values from javascript var to executeSql?

I wrote this code:

```
function BuscaRegistros() {

    var mydata=document.getElementById("lugar").value;
    var mydata2=document.getElementById("fecha").value;

        var db = openDatabase('sightings03', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

    db.transaction(function (tx) {      
      tx.executeSql('SELECT  CommonName FROM Sights03 WHERE location=**"mydata"** AND datte="**mydata2**"' , [], function (tx, results) {
   var len = results.rows.length, i;
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++){

     document.despliega.desp.options[i]=new Option(results.rows.item(i).CommonName,i);

   }
 }, null);

});
}
```

Comment: Are you doing a phonegap application? Why don't you use localStorage API. It's way easier and cleaner
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to concatenate strings?  You do that with the `+` operator.

In general it's like this:

```
var mydata = "hello";
var string = "the value is: " + mydata;
console.log(string); // the value is: hello
```

So you might do:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT  CommonName FROM Sights03 WHERE location="' + mydata + '" AND datte="' + mydata2 + "' , [], function (tx, results) {
```

Comment: now i understand: the argument of a "executeSql" is a string, all clear